# Constrained optimization in SciPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I need, for a simulation, to find the argument (parameters) that maximizes a multivariable function with constraints.

I've seen that scipy.optimize.minimize gives the minimum of a function (and, the maximum of the minus function) of a given function and I can use constraints and bounds. But, reading the doc, I've find out that it returns the minimum value but not the parameter that minimizes it (am I right?)

scipy.optiminize.fmin does give the parameter that minimize the function, but this doesn't accept bounds or contraints.

Looking in numpy, there is a function called argmin but it takes a vector as argument and return the "parameter" that minimizes it.

**Is there such a function that, like minimize, accept constraint and, like fmin, return the parameter that minimize the function?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new [`minimize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) function takes a `bounds` argument when used with certain optimization algorithms. In older SciPy, you need to call one of these algorithms directly, e.g. [`fmin_l_bfgs_b`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b.html).

Answer (score 1):

The returned value of scipy.optimize.minimize is of type Result:

Result contains, among other things, the inputs (x) which minimize f.